# C++ Simulation keep compiling forever

Tags: c++, vivado-hls

I'm using Vitis HLS to run C++ simulations for my project. My program is to conduct matrix calculations for likelihood computing in signal processing. I wrote my matrix library since it should be fixed-point with the static array. It's very weird that Vitis HLS compiler (MingGW 64-bits) keeps compiling the code forever. Below is the code that causes my program problem.

```
    for(int j =0; j < 2048;j++)
    {
        getColMat_L2S(particle,j,&temp_X);
        printf("sth\n");
//      show_mat(particle);
        Mat_S temp_X4 = ObsJacobian(&temp_X,index,&msmtinfo);
//      showmat_S(&temp_X2);
        Mat_S temp_X5 = GISobs_model(&temp_X,index,&msmtinfo);
//      showmat_S(&temp_X5);
//      showmat_S(&msmtinfo.z);
        FP::fixed pzx = GISPzx(&msmtinfo,&Pxx_,&temp_X4,&temp_X5);
        pzx_du = pzx;
        printf("%f_%d\t",pzx_du,j);
        new_wt.entries[j] = wt->entries[j]*pzx;
    }
    show_mat(&new_wt);
    return new_wt;
```

Currently, I have 2 data types, `Mat` and `Mat_S`. `Mat` is an array of `13x2048` fixed point elements (32 bits), and `Mat_S` is an array of `13x13` fixed point elements. Most of my functions used `Mat_S` for computation, except `getColMat_L2S`, which returns a chosen column of input `Mat particles` and saved it to `Mat_S temp_X`.

I am pretty sure that my functions, `getColMat_L2S`, `ObsJacobian`, `GISobs_model`, and `GISPzx`, are tested well, and there should be no problems with them. I have my function `show_mat` and `showmat_S` used to print out all of the elements inside the matrix.

When I commented all `show_mat` and `showmat_S` inside the loop, the compiler took forever for compiling when it was supposed to print some values at the end of the loop. After uncommenting one of `show_mat` or `showmat_S` function. The simulation, this time, prints the Matrix values and the final value. However, it only prints up to 118 over 2048 values. Then the simulation again keeps running forever (I have tested it, even after 1 hour, there is nothing happened !)

I did use the debugger to check if there is anything happening when I comment and uncomment `show_mat` or `showmat_S` functions. However, it's working pretty well in both cases during 10 iterations. The only problem is that it does not print anything at the console. I assumed this may be the Vitis HLS debugger's bug.

Do you have any ideas about where this bug may come from? I'm quite desperate at this moment.

Comment: Keeps compiling forever or keeps running forever?

Comment: *"The simulation, this time, prints the Matrix values and the final value. However, it only prints up to 118 over 2048 values. Then the simulation again keeps running forever"* - Compiling != running. They're not synonymous (unless, of course, you're talking about a *compiler* program). If this code is printing *anything*, that means its done compiling and is thereafter *running*. E.g. you have what appears to be an infinite/unexpected loop *somewhere*.

Comment: At first, It was compiling forever since it does not print anything at all. If I uncomment `show_mat`, it prints some values, so at this point, I believe it finishes compiling and was stuck inside a loop. That's why I used _running_  instead of _compiling_ here.

Comment: @WhozCraig I did check all of them. Since I tested individually each function in 2048 iterations, they all work fine. These functions are completely independent they just provide the output for other functions' input. 

However, I have to use an external library from Vitis inside one of these functions and to be honest, I have no ideas what they are doing.

Comment: "At first, It was compiling forever since it does not print anything at all." You should not expect your program to print anything before you finished compiling and otherwise building and have started it. Something is odd with your description. Probably a misunderstanding of what "compiling" and "running" mean and what the difference is. Maybe you understood after the comments above. In that case please [edit] to clarify.